# How do I add records to a table from a text file?

Tags: c#, append, text-files

I have a table called statelist that looks like this:

```
abbrev nvarchar(2);
name   nvarchar(50);
```

I have a text file called state_list.txt which has a list of states in this format:

```
'AL','Alabama'
'AK','Alaska'
'AR','Arkansas'
```

I want to get the data from the text file into the statelist table. Is there some kind of SQL Insert or other code to do this?

Comment: That is a CSV, parse it or use a tool like CSVHelper to return a typed list, or load it directly to a datatable with OLEDB

Comment: Give *something* a try and post a question when you get stuck

Comment: string[] parts = Textreader.Readline().Split(','); com.Parameter.AddWithValue("@state",parts[0]); com.Parameter.AddWithValue("@State_Name",parts[1]); Searching for those classes will give you an idea on how to implement them. If you get stuck, post your code and the specific problem you're having.

Answer (score 1):

Well you didnt specify things like your database etc but this would be my best guess. i build this for a MsSql databse but you can adjust it for mySql in a few simple steps(First install mySQL connector). 
I dont have a MsSQl database at my disposal atm so i didnt try it at home but it should work like this. Ofcourse edit the connection string so it fits your database

```
        string fileName = "state_list.txt";
        var lines = File.ReadLines(fileName);

        Dictionary<string,string> splitted = new Dictionary<string,string>();
        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            string[] splitter = line.Split(',');
            splitted.Add(splitter[0], splitter[1]); //Add eatch splitted line to dictionary so you can use key and value to insert into table
        }


        string connStr ="server = localhost; user = root; database = yourdb; port = 3306; password = xxxxxxxxx;"; // CREATE CONNECTION WITH YOUR DATABASE INFORMATION
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand comm = conn.CreateCommand();
            comm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO state_list(code,area) VALUES(@code, @area)";

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in splitted)
            {
                comm.Parameters.Add("@code", pair.Key);
                comm.Parameters.Add("@areas", pair.Value);
                comm.ExecuteNonQuery(); // INSERT EACH PAIR INTO DATABASE
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        conn.Close(); //CLOSE CONNECTION
```

Answer (score 0):

One way I can think of is reading each line from text file using `ReadLine()`, and then use `Split(',')` on that line to get the abbreviation and name in a string array, and then you can easily add them to your database in a while loop.

Answer (score 0):

(1)Parse the .txt file and (2)add the records to the DB.  You can use entity framework, or any other ORM, or use ADO like @Jurriaan suggested.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Entity Framework, you can use this approach.

```
   using(var context = new YourContext())
   {
        List<YourEntity> entities = new List<YourEntity>();
        File.ReadAllLines("PathToFile")
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(s =>
            {
               string[] split = s.Split(',');
               someList.Add(new YourEntity(split[0], split[1])); // Or set properties if not using a constructor.
            });

        context.YourTable.AddRange(entities);
        context.SaveChanges();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ' from the file and then run below command.

```
Bulk Insert [dbo].[TableName]
From 'C:\FileName.csv'
with
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', -- For Comma Seperated File
RowTerminator = '\n' -- RowTernimator i.e new Line
)
```

Did this a while back and added to blog at that time -- http://dotnetdevblog.blogspot.com/2007/10/bulk-inserting-from-csv-file-into.html